# How do I sanitize a workflow uploaded by a user?

Tags: xpath, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant application that may run arbitrary workflows as needed.

I plan on using the workflow designer to create these workflows, but even if I limit the Activities in the Toolbox, that doesn't prevent a malicious user from editing his own XAML file, doing activities I'd rather them not (specifically calling out to the .NET framework)

For a given workflow, how do I verify that the only actions being used are those I approve of?  Is an XPath query the only way, or is there a feature within WF that will validate this?

If you need a visual introduction to what I'm looking for [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wfxbap) is a sample project and [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-WF4-Designer-in-the-Browser/) referring to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just load the workflows in a [sandboxed AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx).  You can Use the [GetStandardSandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitymanager.getstandardsandbox) static method of the SecurityManager to set this up relatively easily (and safely).

Of course, I haven't actually *done* this yet, but I'm definitely thinking about adding some of this to my current WF code (which does use AppDomains to isolate execution of workflows from my application).

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is load the XAML as XML and check what is in there. And make sure to check any VB expression entered as users can put interesting things in there as well.

Comment: Thanks; do you have any tips for how to check a VB expression when extracted from XML?  I'm not a VB person so I have a steep curve when it comes to syntax security

Comment: I have never had to parse them but tgey are VisualBasicValue<T> and the Expression property points to the AST.